# ASP.Net MVC ActionResult returns cached View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

After asking several questions on how to refresh a page depending on a selected value of a dropdown control I now have a new question - Somehow my "ChangeLanguage" Method returns a cached version of my View.

View:

```
@model ViewModels.HomeViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title id="Title">Default</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Header">
    <div class="HeaderTextArea">
        <span id="HeaderText">
            @Model.Title.Where(o => o.Language.Equals(Model.SelectedLanguage)).FirstOrDefault().ControlText
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="HeaderImageArea">
        <img id="RB_Image" src="~/Content/Images/RB_Logo.png" alt="RB_IMAGE" />
    </div>
    <div class="LanguageSelection">
        @{
            @Html.DropDownList("SelectedLanguage", new SelectList(Model.AvailableLanguages, "ID", "Description"))
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

```
<script>
var url = '@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage", "Home")';
$('#SelectedLanguage').change(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, {
        ID: $(this).val(), Model: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
        });
});
```

Note that this is my Layout-View. I also tried this on my Index with the same result.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ViewModels.HomeViewModel HVM { get; private set; }
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.HVM = new ViewModels.HomeViewModel();
        this.HVM.SelectedLanguage = this.HVM.AvailableLanguages.First();
        return View(this.HVM);
    }

    public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(int id, ViewModels.HomeViewModel model) {
        model.SelectedLanguage = model.AvailableLanguages.Where(o => o.ID.Equals(id)).First();
        model.SelectedTitle = model.Title.Where(o => o.Language.Equals(model.SelectedLanguage)).First();
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

The ChangeLanguage Method gets called, modifies the required data and returns a "new" View as expected - the logic inside the View does it's job, too - but the expected content does not show up - instead the data from the "first View" shows up. So the data and the displayed data differs.

Ps. I know that Views should be dumb and no logic should be placed inside - but this is just for test purpose. At the end everything should be located inside my ViewModels.

Comment: Your making an ajax call which stays on the same page and you ajax call does not update the DOM. And do not pass the model back to the method (just the selected ID and initialize a new instance)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want the page to full reload after a new value has been selected - isn't this the right way? I thought returning a new View would render a whole new page? Is there another way instead of using Ajax? And if I get you right it's better practice to instantiate a new ViewModel everytime the Language gets changed?

Comment: No its not the right way. There is no point at all using ajax if you want to refresh the whole view (in fact your implementation is just making it slower that a normal submit). But why do a full refresh anyway - it would be better to just update just part of the DOM (return a partial view and update the DOM in the ajax success callback). Otherwise, put the dropdown list in a form, submit it normally and pass the selected ID to a GET method which initializes a new instance based on the language ID and return the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hard words but they're fairly true. It's my first Web project and I'm trying to get in this web development stuff. Thank you very much for your help, without you I wouldn't have got it to work.

Comment: You're making the ajax call, so browser will cache the request. Append the  current datetime in query string of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not cacheing anything. An ajax call stays on the same page. You are calling a method which returns a view (it should be a partial view) but then you don't do anything with that content (i.e. update the DOM). Your script also uses `$.getJSON()` which expects json, yet your controller method returns html so it would not work anyway. In addition, do not pass back the whole model using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)`. That would pass the original model (unchanged) which you already have access to in the controller so its just degrading performance.

3 options you could consider

1. Pass the selected language to a controller method that returns json
   as I indicated in my answer to one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257173/asp-net-mvc-update-viewmodel-on-dropdown-selection-changed).
   This will give the best performance
2. Pass the selected language to a controller method that returns a
   partial view and update the DOM

Controller (note remove `public ViewModels.HomeViewModel HVM { get; private set; }`)

```
public PartialViewResult ChangeLanguage(int id) {
  HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
  model.SelectedLanguage = model.AvailableLanguages.Where(o => o.ID.Equals(id)).First();
  model.SelectedTitle = model.Title.Where(o => o.Language.Equals(model.SelectedLanguage)).First();
  return PartialView(model); // the partial just contains the elements you want to update
}
```

View

```
<div id="mycontent"></div>

$('#SelectedLanguage').change(function () {
  $('#mycontent').load(url, { ID: $(this).val() });
});
```

3. If your not concerned with performance, put the dropdownlist in a form with a submit button and do a normal submit (there is no real point in using ajax if you want to generate a complete new view)

Answer (score 0):

add OutputCache attribute as shown below

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
 public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(int id, ViewModels.HomeViewModel model) {
```